# Tracking HubSpot forms submission conversions in GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, hubspot

I have multiple HubSpot forms on site. I need to track each on setting up conversion goals in GA. Ideally, I'd like to be able to track how organic traffic is converting.

I set up goals as explained here: https://medium.com/@dillonjones/the-easiest-way-to-setup-hubspot-form-tracking-in-google-analytics-a8ad9ab1fc4d

The problem is that since it tracks an Event, it triggers a conversion for all HubSpot forms, no matter which one is filled in.

Is there a way to set it up to track the conversion for HubSpot per destination page? All forms have separate thank you pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you configure 2 different goals, one for each form (for example by distinguishing them with the event label), you can make sure that the two forms are activated separately, however if you have many forms all the same, for the current session you will not be activated more than one goal for each type of goal per session.

You can always rely on events, perhaps by writing the landing page url in the label to more easily distinguish them in Analytics.